# Libgdx | Custom Action

Tags: libgdx

How can I create a custom action for an actor in libgdx? If I can't, than is there at least an action to run a custom piece of code (eg. call a method action)? Thanks.

EDIT:
I created this class :

```
class GapSizeAction extends TemporalAction {

private float newSize;
private Blocker blocker;

public static GapSizeAction getRotateAction(float newSize, float duration) {
    return new GapSizeAction(newSize, duration);
}

public GapSizeAction(float newSize, float duration) {
    super(duration);
    System.out.println("Construct");
    this.blocker = (Blocker)target;
    this.newSize = newSize;
}

private float start, end;

protected void begin() {
    System.out.println("Begin");
    start = blocker.gap;
}

protected void update(float percent) {
    blocker.gap = (start + (end - start) * percent);
}

}
```

The problem is that I am using a custom actor with a gap member (float). I try to cast the target to a blocker so that I can access the gap member variable, but gap ends up being null. I can confirm that gap is not null, I initialize it in the constructor. The blocker (Custom actor) is not null either. Am I going about this wrong?

Comment: Use RunnableAction to call a method in your action. If you want an action that does something gradually over time, extend TemporalAction. Look at the MoveToAction source code for an example of how to do this.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I'm having troubles. I implemented  TemporalAction, looked at MoveToAction, then created a class. I will edit the code above to show what I did. It's not working long story short, more details above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the line `this.blocker = (Blocker)target;` in your constructor. When the constructor is called, the action hasn't been set on a target yet, so `target` is null (and so will be `blocker`). Also, since you're changing a single float, you can extend FloatAction and save yourself some code. I would write your class as below. The constructor should be empty to support easy pooling, and you can set it up in your static factory method.

```
class GapSizeAction extends FloatAction {

    public static GapSizeAction getRotateAction(float newSize, float duration){
        GapSizeAction action = Actions.action(GapSizeAction.class);
        action.setEnd(newSize);
        action.setDuration(duration);
        return action;
    }

    protected void begin () {
        if (target instanceof Blocker)
            setStart(((Blocker)target).gap);
        else
            Gdx.app.logError("Target is not a blocker: " + target.toString());
        super.begin();
    }

    protected void update (float percent) {
        super.update(percent);
        if (target instanceof Blocker)
            ((Blocker)target).gap = getValue();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Fade In Action for example :

```
actor.AddAction(Actions.fadeIn(2.0f));
```

Comment: I know how to do that, I am asking how to create a custom action.